# Cannot Upload Go Binary to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: go, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to build a go binary on my local machine and upload the binary to elastic beanstalk. The reason I would like to do it this way, rather than uploading the bundle and allowing it to build during deployment is to avoid dependency issues.

When I upload a zip with the binary included, it fails during the build step:

```
 application.go:53:2: cannot find package "github.com/battle-gopath-server/..."
 ...
 Failed to start This is eb-buildtask on build.
```

which implies it is trying to build application.go rather than just running the provided binary and runs into the exact dependency issues I am trying to avoid. If I only supply the binary (or just leave out application.go) in the zip folder, it runs into other issues that also imply it is looking for something to build and can't find it (I will try to find the error message).

A few things I have already tried/verified:

- GOOS/ARCH=linux/amd64
- I added a .ebingore file (doesn't work with or without)
- the binary is named application, and the main go file is named application.go
- the binary file is located in bin/

I have also tried uploading the [demo project](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-getstarted.html) provided by aws by building a binary first. As far as I can tell it always attempts to build, rather than running the provided binary.

So the question is how can I skip the build step so elastic beanstalk just runs the provided application binary?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, EB specifically builds and deploys Go projects from source, it does not seem to be built for executing prebuilt binaries (if it was, there would be no reason to have a "Go" stack type, as a Go binary, once built, is just a binary).

Comment: Check out the second bullet point [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html). It says it is possible to deploy binaries.

Comment: Are you providing a buildfile in the package or just a procfile?

Comment: Neither. I did not think this was unnecessary as it is only mentioned for "more complex go applications"